# Your opinion: series of questions regarding Miklos Schweitzer problems

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions, problem-solving

> Do you think it would be fine to post a series of questions regarding problems of the past Miklos Schweitzer competitions?

Since the problems are not trivial at all and the solutions are not published anywhere (at least not in any English texts for recent years), it is difficult to find solutions to them. Some of them are very interesting and I would like to see a solution if I can't find one. ([This problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/42624/double-sum-miklos-schweitzer-2010) turned into an interesting discussion)

Comment: As long as they are past problems and not part of a currently running contest I see no reason why not.

Comment: Remember to mention where the problems come from.

Comment: If I were looking for discussion of a past contests like this, I would try http://www.artofproblemsolving.com

Comment: @GEdgar is right: There is [a section at AoPS](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/resources.php?c=2&cid=152) devoted to this competition. Solution of some problems can be found there. (But even in that case, it might be appropriate to ask the question here; if you look for more solutions. And not all of the problems have solutions at AoPS.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak: Yes, I visit that section a lot, and some problems do have solutions there. I will not post those as questions here. I think that some problems which are harder will not get a solution at AoPS, and that's why I thought it might be a good idea to post some as questions here.

Comment: @BeniBogosel: I have just posted one of the more difficult ones [here.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/563640/continuous-functions-on-mathbbr2-with-special-property) (Not saying that other ones aren't difficult; on the contrary, I probably wouldn't be able to solve any one of them in a given lifetime).